Where can I get information on supporting Miracast on Android 13 with an NXP devkit BSP?
I have integrated our company's radios with NXP's imx8mp dev kit with their supplied BSP, but they do not have support for miracast in this BSP, and I would like to see if we can support it.
Where can I get information on adding support for Miracast?  (we currently integrate our radios with Android versions 11-14.)
Is miracast support built into Android by default and I simply need to enable it in the BSP?
Thanks in advance.
I searched for miracast in the android docs but did not find what I needed.
Asked NXP support (they say they have no info)

Miracast is one of the names used, on Android it is just "Cast" as is built in to the OS and can be found under "Settings->Connected Devices->Connection Preferences->Cast" It's part of a Wifi P2P display, some details https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/Wifi/framework/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.java;bpv=1;bpt=1 but no idea on do what you want.

Unfortunately, Google removed native Miracast support from Android starting with Android 9 (Pie). you may use Chromecast as its preferred method for wireless display casting.
